# How to get column type by it's name using reflation?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection

I am using entity framework 6 in my project code first approach. 
context variable  class that inherits from DbContext type.

I have this code:

```
   var table = (IEnumerable)context.GetType().
               GetProperty("TableName").
               GetValue(context, null);
```

From the `table` above I need to get type of the column by it name.

Any idea how can I implement it?

Comment: What is the type of the `context` variable? A class that inherits from `DbContext`? What is the type of the `TableName`  property?

Comment: @YacoubMassad,
 
Yes it's inherits from DbContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `IEnumerable`, you need to cast the table to `IQueryable` and use [IQueryable.ElementType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.elementtype(v=vs.113).aspx) to get the required information, like this

```
var table = (IQueryable)context.GetType().
               GetProperty("TableName").
               GetValue(context, null);
var propertyType = table.ElementType.GetProperty("PropertyName").PropertyType;
```

Comment: How is `TableName` a property of `DbContext`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad I assume OP meant a specific table name as well as property name. In the real case both will be a string variables.